# Robocopy files only with a certain date

Tags: date, robocopy

I am looking to copy files from x: to z: only if the destination file has a date changed of 9/23/2014. If the destination file has an older or newer date, don't touch it. X is my backup and Z is the file server.

For example

```
z:\test1.log 9/18/2014
z:\test2.log 9/23/2014
z:\test3.log 9/27/2014
```

I want Robocopy to look @ the three files on Z, and only copy the files that are in Z as being modified 9/23/2014.

Comment: Robocopy can't do that on it's own.  Use PowerShell and write a script to detect which files should be (robo)copied.

Comment: Have a look at the FORFILES command: http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: Robocopy has a /MAXAGE:n and a /MINAGE:n parameter to exclude files elder/newer than n days. If the wanted day is 7 days before today, you could try to combine /MAXAGE:7 and /MINAGE:7